# Count of Installed Packages in an Org

Tags: installedpackage

An org I am working on, has a large technical debt. As I am reviewing the org, one area where I am looking at is the Installed Packages. I would like to know the following -

- Count of installed packages
- Usage i.e. heavily or sparsely used
- total number of objects (and fields) associated with installed packages.

The query below gives me some insight, however I would like to know more details. That way I can analyze the data.

`Select DurableId, Id, isSalesforce, MajorVersion,MinorVersion,Name, NameSpacePrefix From Publisher`

I would like to know what tools or approaches other have used.

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Count of installed packages

The gold standard today is [Salesforce DX](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.sfdx_dev.meta/sfdx_dev/sfdx_dev_intro.htm):

```
sfdx force:package:installed:list
```

But you could also write a [Tooling API](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_tooling.meta/api_tooling/intro_api_tooling.htm) query:

```
SELECT Id FROM InstalledSubscriberPackage
```

> Usage i.e. heavily or sparsely used

No direct way to get at this, as far as I can tell. You can export the package metadata (e.g. `force:source:retrieve`) and parse the output, and then use `/services/data/v52.0/limits/recordCount?sObjects=Object1,Object2,etc` to get the [storage usage](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.api_rest.meta/api_rest/resources_record_count.htm) for those objects. Cumbersome, but definitely possible with a few API calls and some relatively simple scripts. You could theoretically even write this in pure Apex.

Also, to see how many fields are populated (e.g. non-null values), you might consider taking a [Field Trip](https://help.salesforce.com/s/articleView?id=000321289&type=1). This free package tallies up data usage in all fields/objects you select, and you can then export/report on this information. This helps identify custom fields on standard objects that you otherwise could not easily distinguish from using the above Record Count API call.

> total number of objects (and fields) associated with installed packages.

Both queries below require the Tooling API (not the normal SOAP/REST API).

For fields:

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM CustomField WHERE NamespacePrefix='xyz'
```

For objects:

```
SELECT COUNT() FROM CustomObject WHERE NamespacePrefix='xyz'
```

Working from the above Salesforce DX, though, you can also retrieve the package contents, the use a terminal command to count the number of fields/objects that are used.

---

Basically, there's ways to get at all of this information.